# Does c# build-in async method implement by TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Like streamReader.ReadAsync/downloadAsync and many other async methods,Should they use TaskCompletionSource to implement?

For example the SendAsync method in socket/httpclient.When IOCP send completely,and then IO threadpool get a thread to notify cpu that it work finished,should it call TaskCompletionSource.SetResult in c# to continue await?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like streamReader.ReadAsync/downloadAsync and many other async methods,Should they use TaskCompletionSource to implement?

Sort of. You can think of them as using `TaskCompletionSource<T>`, and that's close enough.

Technically, they skip the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and use non-public methods on `Task` to do the same thing.

> For example the SendAsync method in socket/httpclient.When IOCP send completely,and then IO threadpool get a thread to notify cpu that it work finished,should it call TaskCompletionSource.SetResult in c# to continue await?

Sometimes. Some BCL methods complete on an I/O threadpool (IOCP) thread, but most of them complete on worker threadpool threads. This is to avoid any continuation work (like end-user code after an `await`) from clogging up the IOCP threads. But last time I checked, some lower-level callbacks (particularly socket ones) can be invoked on an I/O thread.